# Reorder column by index number

Tags: python

I have the following column, each row has one value, the left number is the index. I want to reorder going from 1 to 337.

```py
[('oxcondol', 201    1340.629275
305     607.424072
21      344.110115
60      415.400203
248     785.634119
          ...     
8       620.842246
73      430.414746
118     909.090909
189    1097.222222
206    1492.734478
Name: oxcondol, Length: 337, dtype: float64)]
```

I tried looking at the sorted method but doesn't seem to work

Comment: did you check sort_values https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Instead, you can try to use the sort_values() method in pandas to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [sort_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = ... # your dataframe

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```